# sequelize return only first row ( through the include association)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

i am using sequelize include to associate the next three models

"moldsets" has many "molds" and "molds" has many "moldstatus"

```
// moldsets.model.js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const moldsets = sequelizeClient.define(
    "moldsets",
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      vendor: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      number_of_blanks: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      number_of_blows: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      date_of_reception: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      date_of_scrap: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  moldsets.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    const { molds } = models;
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    moldsets.hasMany(molds, { foreignKey: "moldsetId" });
  };

  return moldsets;
};

//molds.model.js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const molds = sequelizeClient.define(
    "molds",
    {
      number: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      kind: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      moldsetId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      numberOfTotalGobs: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      statusId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      note: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  molds.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    console.log(models);
    const { moldsets, moldstatus } = models;
    molds.belongsTo(moldsets);
    molds.hasMany(moldstatus, { as: "status" });
  };

  return molds;
};


// moldstatus.model.js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const moldstatus = sequelizeClient.define(
    "moldstatus",
    {
      moldId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      startdate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      enddate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },

      note: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },

      lineId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      section: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      defect: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },

      numberOfGobs: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      operatorId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  moldstatus.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    const { molds } = models;
    moldstatus.belongsTo(molds, { foreignKey: "statusId" });
  };

  return moldstatus;
};
```

but when i query the moldset ( i am using feathersjs so i am using it in the before find hook )

```
const related = async (context) => {
  const sequelize = context.app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const { molds, moldstatus } = sequelize.models;
  context.params.sequelize = {
    include: [
      //{ all: true, nested: true },
      {
        model: molds,
        attributes: ["number", "statusId"],
        required: false,
        order: [[molds, "number", "ASC"]],
        include: [
          {
            model: moldstatus,
            as: "status",
            required: false,
            attributes: ["status"],
            //order: [[moldstatus, "created_at", "DESC"]],
          },
        ],
        raw: false,
      },
    ],
    raw: false,
  };
  return context;
};

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [
      authenticate("jwt"),
      (context) => {
        related(context);
      },
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },
};
```

the result is i got all the moldsets with its molds but i got only the first mold status for the first mold only in each moldset ( the other molds got empty array )
i tried setting raw to true but i still got the status for the first mold in each moldset only ...

```
//result
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "fruity250ml1",
    "vendor": "jacob",
    "status": "mounted",
    "number_of_blanks": 30,
    "number_of_blows": 28,
    "date_of_reception": "2021-04-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "date_of_scrap": null,
    "createdAt": "2021-04-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "molds": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "statusId": 3,
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "mounted"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "statusId": 4,
            "status": []
        }
    ],
    "mounted": null
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "seles250ml1",
    "vendor": "omco",
    "status": "avalible",
    "number_of_blanks": 30,
    "number_of_blows": 28,
    "date_of_reception": "2021-07-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "date_of_scrap": null,
    "createdAt": "2021-07-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T13:22:00.000Z",
    "molds": [
        {
            "number": 2,
            "statusId": 2,
            "status": []
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "statusId": 3,
            "status": []
        },
        {
            "number": 1,
            "statusId": 3,
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "avalible"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

database :
molds:
[image: molds]
moldstatus:
[image: moldstatus]
moldsets:
[image: moldsets]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you indicate a foreign key field in some association explicitly you should indicate it for the reversed association as well:

```js
moldsets.hasMany(molds, { foreignKey: "moldsetId" });
...
molds.belongsTo(moldsets, { foreignKey: "moldsetId" });
```

```js
molds.hasMany(moldstatus, { as: "status", foreignKey: "statusId" });
...
moldstatus.belongsTo(molds, { foreignKey: "statusId" });
```

And you indicated incorrect foreign key field for `molds.hasMany(moldstatus` so the above associations should be like this:

```js
molds.hasMany(moldstatus, { as: "status", foreignKey: "moldId" });
...
moldstatus.belongsTo(molds, { foreignKey: "moldId" });
```